# Create a canvas with layer management

Tags: javascript, next.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs, konvajs

I want to integrate a fully working canvas in my Next.js application with the feature to add layers over the canvas such that each layer can have it's own strokes (made by the user) and images (uploaded by the user). Of course just like any canvas application, it should have the feature to draw strokes, erase them and drag and resize uploaded images as well. The user should also be able to rearrange layers as to their liking.

Initially I tried using `fabric.js` canvas library since it's quite powerful and offers features like dragging and rotating objects in the canvas with ease. The only problem with it is that it does not have an in-built layer management system. It puts all of the objects in the canvas in a `stack-like` list where the position of the object in the list determines it's `z-index` position in the canvas. So no two objects can ever be in the same layer. Although we can send objects down a layer or up a layer but there is no dedicated layer management.

Next up, I used `konva.js`. It has an in-built layer management system where any update to a single layer should not re-render the entire canvas but should only updated the affected layer. But I found the eraser to just **overdraw** over the canvas with the background color of the canvas even if we use `destination-out` as a `globalCompositeOperation`. This is in fact demonstrated when we erase some stroke on the canvas and then drag an image in the area where the stroke was erased. The image gets covered by the strokes made by the eraser even though they are in the same layer.
[image: Here by attached is a GIF to demonstrate the same]

Comment: You could maybe use either lib if they both allow transparent backgrounds, one idea is maybe place 2 instances of the canvas on top, you could then flip the order in the DOM alter z-index etc, maybe even `pointer-events:none` to enable disable layers.  ps. They are just some ideas, not 100% sure if it would work, but not sure why it wouldn't.

Comment: @Keith here the user would have the option to add as many layers as they want. Having multiple canvas instances would prove to be too heavy to ensure consistent performance. I did try this out but it kind of defeats the purpose of having this as a feature when it affects performance

Comment: Yeah, I did wonder about the performance aspect, but out of curiosity I just created one with 100 layers, and it didn't seem to struggle, did a 1000 layers, and things started to go a bit clunky.

Comment: Having many layers in Konva will hurt performance.  You are overengineering your solution - better to manage the concept of what you call 'layers' with groups on a single layer, or even manage the z-index of shapes to give the illusion of layers. All completely possible.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat but in my case, users should be able to rearrange layers by dragging them in the stack as you can see from the GIF. There is a card which shows an image of the present state of the layer and in case of multiple layers users can drag any layer to position them accordingly in the stack. How would grouping objects together help me ? I would need to create a group every time the user draws anything on the canvas

Comment: Layers are  construct for the convenience of the user. How you realise the feature in the code of your app is your decision. I am pointing out that a Konva diagram with many layers may experience performance problems, and suggesting that another way to handle layering would be groups. Of you could ignore groups and just associate shapes that are physically all on one layer as being layered.  Whatever your approach you would handle 'layering' in your model and manage output to the Konva accordingly.  You do have a model, right?